# How to set the screen resolution dynamically in Asp.Net application with C# as language

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to set the screen resolution dynamically in Asp.Net application with C# as language

I have created an asp.net app on my machine where the resolution is

> set to 1280 x 1024. When my users view the form on their screen, some
>   of the controls display differently than on my screen. One solution I
>   have is to use some javascript to determine the resolution of their
>   screen and redirect them to a duplicate form suited better for their
>   resolution but I would have to maintain multiple forms. Anybody know
>   of a better way to handle resolution problems in asp.net? Thanks in
>   advance

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS and percentage-based widths

Answer (score 1):

You can't set the screen resolution from a web app.  A web app runs inside a browser, and it doesn't have access to the client OS functions.

Your best bet is to target a minimum screen resolution, and program your form layout for that.

1024x768 is a safe bet for minimum resolution these days.